# Countifs column I until column a changes then save and restart count

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the following to count values in a workbook.worksheet that is then used in another workbook `iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("I:I"), "5", Range("H:H"), "****)` and this works for the current needs.

HOWEVER, I just found out that these reports are being combined and I now need to make the same count but save that to a variable, reset the count and start again when column a changes. i have been trying to figure this out for about a week now but no luck...

so the set of data would look something like the following:
[sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6QHb.png)

Please Help !!

Comment: What is the expected output given your sample dataset?

Comment: What do you mean "Save it to a variable". You have a variable `iVal`. If you need to reset it, set it equal to zero? Seems too simple. Try to articulate your specific problem with better clarity of what you're trying to accomplish, what you are doing and how the outcome is not what you expect.

Comment: If you need to "reset" the variable but maintain the 1st value(s) you could establish an array. For each column change and ```ival()``` "reset", the values would be maintained.

Comment: I normally use the current variables to be processed further down in other worksheets now with the new changes  I will noit be able to do this as i need to process this by IP (column 1) when column 1 changes to a different IP i need to save IVal to another Variable (which i can use to process) then reset IVal and start the process over currently my next step is to close the workbook and process but i cannot do that now as i have multiple IP's now showing in a single dataset. hope that helps some?!?!

Comment: Basically what i need to be able to do is break this down by column a (ip) and process each IP separately the old reports i was being fed only had a single ip per report. now i will be getting several could be 3 could be 30 depending on the report.

Comment: @PGSystemTester - Sorry i am not a developer I only dabble and for the most part have been getting along fine however this one has me stumped. this has been running correctly and will continue to do so until the new change happens. Currently i get 1 ip per report and that is what this is built to process. Very soon i will be getting several IP's per report and i need to process each ip seperatly if that helps.